# Cannot see all mounted disks until/unless I ls them first

Tags: linux, disk

This is an annoying problem that I suspect others have...

First, please excuse the nontechnical way I articulate this.  I'm not a disk expert.

We have a bunch of disks all mounted under "/proj".  E.g. "/proj/alpha", "/proj/beta", "/proj/gamma".  If I do an ls on /proj, I only see alpha.  If I do a direct "ls /proj/beta", I see it.  If I then do a "ls /proj", I see it now whereas I didn't before.  It's like you have to kick it with a direct ls before you can see it under /proj.  Inspection of the "/proj" file shows that beta was missing.... until I did an ls on it, then it's in the /proj file.

Why is that and is there anything I can do to flush them all out ?  Problem is, I don't know what all the files are under /proj, so I can't kick the ones I don't know about

Comment: Is automount involved?

Comment: automount ?  How can I determine if that's enabled ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

This is a guess and something to try.

ls /*  or ls /proj/*